# How to use web push notifications with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, push-notification

I am just hoping to find some good examples, but I haven't found anything. Pushjs is working on localhost, but how do I use the service worker correctly? I have linked the file, but this:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('Received a push message', event);

    // var notificationOptions = {
    //     body: 'The highlights of Google I/O 2015',
    //     icon: 'images/icon@192.png',
    //     tag: 'highlights-google-io-2015',
    //     data: null
    // };

    var notificationOptions = {
      body: "Martin matches 89% with you!",
      icon: '/images/LogoStore.jpg',
      timeout: 4000,
      link: "/",
      onClick: function () {
          window.focus();
          this.close();
      }
    }

    if (self.registration.showNotification) {
        self.registration.showNotification('Timely News', notificationOptions);
        return;
    } else {
        new Notification('Timely News', notificationOptions);
    }
});
```

does not work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? How do you intend it to work? Can you please give some example of the expected output?

Comment: maybe this question is too broad, but I want to trigger the notification from the server. As far as I understood it, I need to get a service worker that is stored in the client browser (so this works even when the user is not on the page) and then send a command to GCM which forwards it to the correct client. I just cannot find any example or documentation on how to do that with meteor

Comment: Meteor is just javascript. Whatever the instructions are for JS will be the same for meteor